# large array of numbers vs smaller array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, object

What would be faster when it comes to iterating over all the elements?

**Method 1:**

```
let array = [10, 0, 0, 20, 1, 0, 12, 2, 0];

for(let i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i += 3) {
    doSomething(array[i], array[i + 1], array[i + 2]);
}
```

vs

**Method 2:**

```
let array = [{id:10, x:0, y:0}, {id:20, x:1, y:0}, {id:12, x:2, y:0}];

for(let i = 0, l = array.length, current = null; i < l; ++i) {
    current = array[i];
    doSomething(current.id, current.x, current.y);
    // i'm aware that we could make doSomething work with the object
    // -> even a thing to consider?
}
```

My guess is that we're faster with **1**, but you guys may have more intel of v8, spidermonkey and all that so maybe the object handling and the smaller array would be faster in the end?

Comment: Why don't you use `Date.now()` and see for yourself?

Comment: method 1 should be faster, but method 2 is better way to organize the data you are using.

Comment: I don't think accessing object properties this or that way make a big change in 2016. I would expect both doing the same in terms of performance.

Comment: why are you asking? best guess is  the differences are likely very minor and  you are most likely over optimizing

Comment: You can check by yourself using [Performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now)

Comment: @HarshalCarpenter Can you provide reasoning for that, please?

Comment: i actually wanted to know a bit more about the _why_ stuff's faster or slower, but the guys down there told me well enough for now :)

Comment: @Bergi According to my analysis, method 1: should be faster as he is accessing only in 1 step, and in method 2 he is getting the value by accessing in 2 steps(first the array for object and then value inside object), so it seems like method 1 is faster. But method 2 can be much easier to read in the future if the array has lot of values. If I had to design a game then also I would surely use the method 2 rather than method 1. I am just thinking here. Correct me if I am wrong. :)

Comment: @HarshalCarpenter Counting "steps" (whatever that is) is ok for complexity analysis, but not for performance analysis. #1 has three indexed array accesses and three additions, while #2 has a single indexed array access, a single addition, and three (constant, very cheap) property accesses. They're hardly comparable without bytecode analysis or benchmarking.

Comment: @Bergi Yes. constant and very cheap.. nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are `O(n)`. Nothing else matters. Even their memory consumption will only differ minimally. You can do a benchmark yourself when you think that this is performance-critical, but [it most likely isn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimisation).

Use objects because they provide a clear structure for your data and make your code more readable. Yes, you should consider passing such an object to `doSomething`.

Comment: thanks for talking about the intel of memory management a lil' bit, i guess i'll go with the second way then, @dadykhoff's test showed me that it wont even be critical in a game code.

Answer (score 0):

Running both of your methods https://www.measurethat.net/ tells that Method 1 is faster by ~2,300 operations/second.

https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/ShowResult/1363

Comment: "2300 ops/s" is pretty meaningless. Saying that snippet 2 runs about 12% slower than snippet 1 would be reasonable, but actually that benchmark is flawed like so many microbenchmarks.

Comment: that is browser and os dependent also .... i tried in 2 browsers and were reasonably close in both

Comment: Hmm thanks for the JSPerf replacement. They resulted the same in FF v50 and almost the same in Chrome v54

Comment: In https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/ShowResult/1364 the second one was even faster

Comment: thanks for testing, i was planning to use this in a loop next to a render - in short - for a game, so i thought this kinda micro-optimization is necessary.